# CNAME redirect domain to www

Tags: web-hosting

On my `example.com` domain name at Godaddy's page, I set a CNAME record `www` to point to `test.somedomain.example`. So if a user types in `www.example.com`, it will takes him to `test.somedoman.example`.

My question is I how can I configure `example.com` to point to `www.example.com`? That way if a user types in `example.com` or `www.example.com`, both will take him to `test.somedomain.example`

Answer (score 2):

Erik's answer is correct if you just want the domains to alias each other. Although, it's better for user experience and SEO purposes to use an HTTP redirect using a `.htaccess` file in your web root. Or, GoDaddy may provide soem more user friendly means of doing this.

If not, just create a file named `.htaccess` in the FTP directory for `example.com` with the line:

```
Redirect 301 / http://test.somedomain.example
```

Then anyone who has their browser visit `example.com` will be redirected to `test.somedomain.example` - *and* you'll help out your search engine rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a CNAME record for `example.com` pointing to `www.example.com`, or to `test.somedomain.example`. No problem...

Comment: This answer is not correct.  A `CNAME` record is [not allowed for the bare domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain).

Answer (score 0):

At [GoDaddy, you can set up domain forwarding](https://www.godaddy.com/help/edit-my-domain-forwarding-19978) to redirect your domain.

When you chose a `CNAME` for www, that points the domain to the same IP address as `test.somedoman.example`.  It is up to the server at that address how to handle the request for your domain.  It could:

- Redirect to `test.somedoman.example`
- Show the same content as `test.somedoman.example`
- Show entirely different content altogether
- Give an error

The `CNAME` itself doesn't redirect.  It just causes requests to get routed to the same server as the other domain.   That is why using GoDaddy's domain forwarding is usually preferable.

If the server at `test.somedoman.example` is (or could be) configured to redirect properly, you could also point the bare domain (apex) there.  However, you can't use a `CNAME` record for that.  For the domain apex you would need to use an `A` record with the IP address of server for `test.somedoman.example`.  So your records could look like where `@` is usually used to represent the bare domain (domain apex, `example.com` with no `www`:

```
@     A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www   CNAME   test.somedomain.example
```

or you could just use the `A` record in both cases:

```
@     A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www   A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```